# Does jqGrid Able to Make Search Boolean Like 'This Picture'?

Tags: jqgrid

I want to implement multiple search with boolean data.

Does jqGrid able to make search with dropdown?

In mysql table, value for accredited field is boolean (0/1). 
I am showing boolean value in presentation table is "not accredited or accredited".
And I want to search through this value. 
So, as picture shown above, we can pick dropdown which accredited or not accredited instead of type 0 or 1.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is just usage of `stype: "select"` property in definition of `accredited` column in `colModel` and definition of [searchoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config#colmodel_options) which corresponds you data. For example

```js
stype: "select",
searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: "0:not accredited;1:accredited" }
```